# How to override array parameter in psake script

Tags: arrays, powershell, properties, psake

Let us assume my my psake default.ps1 looks like this :

```
properties { $dllsToMerge= @("x.dll","y.dll")}
task ilmerge {
  exec { &ilmerge -dll $dllsToMerge -out single.dll}
}
```

now when running this task at some times I would like to change which assemblies get merged. For example :

```
invoke-psake ilmerge -properties @{"dllsToMerge"="@("x.dll","y.dll","z.dll")"}
```

for some reason the above command does not work as it is not able to parse the string as array. Any way to do this without manual parsing and string to array conversion ?

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes from the array value? `@{"dllsToMerge"=@("x.dll","y.dll","z.dll")}`

Comment: I have verified it. It works @MathiasR.Jessen. Submit your comment as answer.